# Why can't use throws Exception here?

Tags: java, exception

Consider following statement

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));
```

Normally we have to `throws` `Exception` or we have to use `try-catch` to handle the `Exception`.

But if I want to use this in a static block as follows. Only thing can do is use `try-catch` block to handle the `Exception`. But can't use `throws` here? What is the reason behind `java` doesn't provide `throws` here?

```
  static {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Let me add this too. The case the block not a static block similar rule apply here.

```
 {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

We can normally do if this in a method as follows

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));
     }
```

Comment: FWIW: Opening a `FileReader` during the static initialization of your class would qualify as a Bad Thing(tm). ;-)

Comment: Just to give you the Language Specification reference: [It is a compile-time error if a class variable initializer ... or static initializer ... of a named class or interface can throw a checked exception class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a static block being run when the class is initialized. Since it's a checked exception, you cannot throw it as there's nowhere to catch it.
throwing an unchecked exception is possible, but it will crash the program, as neither that can be caught anywhere.

Instead, you can put the code in a

```
public static void init() throws FileNotFoundException
{
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));
}
```

And then call that once on your program start up.

Edit: Removing the `static` keyword doesn't change anything in the compiled result. It's just the syntax that allows it to be missing.

Comment: "There's nowhere to throw the exception to" isn't correct. You can still throw unchecked exceptions. The problem is that you can't specify a throws clause, since that wouldn't make much sense. You can still wrap it in a RuntimeException for example.

Comment: @Kayaman But can you catch the unchecked exception you throw? I would believe not, unless you manually load the class with a `ClassLoader` I presume?

Comment: No you can't, since it's not your code that's handling the class initialization. But it just shows that you can let the exception escape the static block, it just can't be a checked exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `static` code block like that is run when your class is loaded (ussualy after JVM starts), so throwing exeption here would crush your entire java program, as you cant catch it anywhere

Comment: *"...when JVM starts..."* No, when the class is loaded, which may be a long time later.

Answer (score 0):

Since an exception escaping the `static` block would cause an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

In other words, don't let Exceptions escape from a static initializer - handle them instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception from init block but it should be an unchecked exception. What you can do is this

```
static {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```